# Perl extract a parameter into hashref

Tags: regex, perl

The URL will be like:

```
/products?includes=images(id,src),image(src),variants,options(title)
```

I'd like to extract the param "includes" and merge them into a single hashref like this:

```
$includes = {
  images => { fields => "id,src" },
  image => { fields => "src" },
  variants => undef,
  options => { fields => "title" }
}
```

I'd split it as ARRAY first but have no idea about sub comma inside the brackets and main comma.

Comment: Why the value of `options` is `undef` instead of `title`?

Comment: I'd probably have a play with [this](http://search.cpan.org/~khs/Parse-Token-Lite-0.120/lib/Parse/Token/Lite.pm) (it's probably overkill though)

Comment: do you always know the query string parameters?

Comment: @LeeDuhem sorry it's typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expression could be used to extract those information, although I believe specific module dedicated (partially) to parse URL is an easier, more reliable solution to this problem.

Here is one possible solution by using regular expression:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $url = '/products?includes=images(id,src),image(src),variants,options(title)';

my %record;

my (undef, $para, $values) = split /\?|=/, $url;

while ($values =~ m/(\w+) (?: \( ([^\)]+) \) ,?)?/xg) {
    my ($key, $fields) = ($1, $2);
    $record{$para}->{$key} = { fields => $fields };
}

print "$url\n";
print Dumper(\%record);
```

---

Output:

```
$ perl t.pl 
/products?includes=images(id,src),image(src),variants,options(title)
$VAR1 = {
          'includes' => {
                          'variants' => {
                                          'fields' => undef
                                        },
                          'images' => {
                                        'fields' => 'id,src'
                                      },
                          'options' => {
                                         'fields' => 'title'
                                       },
                          'image' => {
                                       'fields' => 'src'
                                     }
                        }
        };
```

Comment: thanks a lot! The key point is here:  m/(\w+) (?: \( ([^\)]+) \) ,?)?/xg

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
use strict;
use warnings;

my $query=qq|images(id,src),image(src),variants,options(title)|;

sub rhash {
    my $v=shift;
    my %res=();
    for my $kv (grep(defined($_),$v=~/(\w+\([\w,]+\))|(\w+),/g)) {
        my ($k,$v);
        if ($kv=~/\(/) {
            ($k,$v)=$kv=~/([^(]+)\(([^)]+)\)/;
        } else {
            $k=$kv;
            $v=undef;
        }
    $res{$k}=$v;
    }
    return \%res;
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(rhash($query));
```

This seems a little over complicated, but it works

The line 
`for my $kv (grep(defined($_),$v=~/(\w+\([\w,]+\))|(\w+),/g))`
needs a little explaining

`/(\w+\([\w,]+\))|(\w+),/` grabs any group that is alpha followed by braces or alternatively, just alpha.  After each group of this sort there is a comma.  The `|` in the middle is the alternation operator

The grep defined is used as the regexp I have constructed seems to return unwanted undef values.  I'm sure it could be improved